# Strange exception - Serialization of 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File' is not allowed

Tags: forms, symfony, serialization

I have this exception, in a strange behavior that I can't understand. I'll try to explain.

I have a form, where I can add create a report. The use can upload multiple attached pdf and a text comment. The form have 2 submit button, 'save' and 'saveAndClose'.

```
class ReportType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('documentDatas', CollectionType::class, array(
                'entry_type' => DocumentType::class,
                'entry_options' => ['data_class' => 'AppBundle\Model\DocumentPdfData', 'add_class' => 'upload-pdf'],
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'label' => false
            ))
            ->add('comment', CKEditorType::class, array(
                'config' => array('toolbar' => 'my_toolbar'),
                'label' => false,
                'required' => false,
                'input_sync' => true
            ))
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('attr' => array('class' => 'btn btn-success mr-2')))
            ->add('saveAndClose', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'saveAndClose', 'attr' => array('class' => 'btn btn-success float-right')))
        ;
    }
}
```

The Save only persist the form, the saveAndClose obviously close the report, so user can't modify it anymore.

The exception

> Serialization of 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File' is not allowed

appear when an user upload an attached and saveAndClose the form. Only in this case, other case works well (also upload attached, push save, return the the form and saveAndClose).

This is my controller:

```
 if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            if ($form->getClickedButton() && 'saveAndClose' === $form->getClickedButton()->getName()) {

                    $this->get(ConfirmReport::class)->confirm($report, $user);
                    $em->flush();

                    $report->modify($reportData, $user);

                    $em->persist($report->getReportParameters());
                    $em->persist($report);

                    $em->flush();

                    $this->addFlash('success', $this->get('translator')->trans('ReportConfirmed'));
                    return $this->redirectToRoute('practitioner_visit_detail_to_do');

            }

            if ($form->getClickedButton() && 'save' === $form->getClickedButton()->getName()) {
                $report->modify($ReportData, $user);
                $em->persist($report->getReportParameters());
                $em->persist($report);
                $em->flush();

                $this->addFlash('success', $this->get('translator')->trans('ReportSaved'));
                return $this->redirectToRoute('practitioner_visit_detail_to_do');
            }
        }
```

So, the only difference between 2 flux is the confimReport service. Inside this I put a bool parameter of report to true and make some operation on the DB, to remove some read and write permission of the user on this report. Nothing about the file uploaded or something else. So, i can't understand what cause the exception.

N.B.:

- If i comment the confirmReport service all work well (dont know why);
- I obtain the exception but the entity manager is flushed, so in my db I have saved the operation of the user (also the file uploaded).

So then what else could cause this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the second flushing messes up with the code ? Can you try this :

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid() && $form->getClickedButton()) {
    if ('saveAndClose' === $form->getClickedButton()->getName()) {
        $this->get(ConfirmReport::class)->confirm($report, $user);
        $msg='ReportConfirmed';
    }

    if ('save' === $form->getClickedButton()->getName()) {
        $msg = 'ReportSaved';
    }

    $report->modify($ReportData, $user);
    $em->persist($report->getReportParameters());
    $em->persist($report);
    $em->flush();

    $this->addFlash('success', $this->get('translator')->trans($msg));
    return $this->redirectToRoute('practitioner_visit_detail_to_do');
}
```

Can you also show the content of the `confirm()` function ?

Thanks